# Advanced auto clicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build an advanced auto clicker which means it will click on button after button.
If I run one script after another it will work, like that:

```
$("a.smallFont[tabindex='6']").click();
```

Enter

```
 $("#js_CityPosition14Link").click();
```

Enter..

But when I try to run it all together, the page refreshes and the code won't resume.

```
setTimeout(() => $("a.smallFont[tabindex='6']").click(), 1000);  
setTimeout(() => $("#js_CityPosition14Link").click(), 2000);  
setTimeout(() => $("#js_wallBuildButton").click(), 3000);
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Does the page reload immediately or only after X seconds?

Comment: Hi victory, after the first click, It navigated to a new page (note the first click is for specific <a> tag>.
I'm trying to resuming the script to the new page is reloaded.

Comment: Script lives in your web page. Therefore, when you load a new page, everything in the previous page is destroyed, including running scripts. I don't know a lot about it but maybe you could make this work if it's part of a browser extension, rather than a specific page.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the way scripts run on your browser, whenever you refresh or load a new page it basically throws everything it had out and loads the new content. Same goes with your script, so you're probably better off using a webdriver, or creating a browser extension.